# How to create a hyperlink in a column in telerik grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a grid which contains an id,which is a hyperlink and takes me to a different page.Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the user is working on Telerik-MVC. Here's a sample code.

```
 Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("GridName")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.Id))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title("ID")
            .Template(@<text><a href="http://differentpage?id=@item.RpoId">@item.RpoId</a> </text>);
            columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyA);
            columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyB); //And so on...
        }

    )
    .Render();
```

Have a closer look at how the column is Templated.

Comment: Actually, I'd use the "ClientTemplate" method instead of the "Template" one. Ultimately you have the right answer. Unfortunately for you the question's author probably wont come back to "accepted".

Comment: Then I'd presume that you are doing client side data binding as "ClientTemplates" are not intended to be used in pure server side binding.

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to use the RadGrid, then there is a type of column called the `GridHyperLinkColumn` described here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html

Using RadGrid with MVC: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-radgrid-databinding.html

This example shows what it can look like http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx.

If not, you'll need to use a GridColumnTemplate with a link in it.